# estimates of series involving trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, trigonometric-series

I am following Young's book, An introduction to nonharmonic fourier series, and I am having trouble with the following "obvious" estimates (Ch.1,Sec.10,Th.14):

[image: Estimates]

where $\lvert \delta_n \rvert \leq L <\frac{1}{4}$, and the norm we are working with is $\lVert \cdot\rVert_2$ in $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$.

Analizyng the growth of the involved functions seems pretty difficult, since the zeros of their derivatives are quite tricky. I have tried a more elemental approach, comparing sizes of numerators and denominators, but I found trouble with inequalities of the form

$$\sin{ \pi \delta_n} \geq \sin{ \pi L}$$
or
$$\cos{ \pi \delta_n} \leq \cos{ \pi L},$$

since sine is increasing and cosine is decreasing in $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, so I guess a more subtle bound might be used.

Comment: Notice for example that $1-\sin(x)/x$ is increasing for small $x\geq 0$

Comment: How do you know that?

Comment: I know because $\sin(x)/x$ is the well known cardinal sine function. If you want to prove it  just compute the derivative...

Comment: The derivative of $\sin(x)/x$ is negative between $0$ and the lowest positive solution of $x = \tan x$, which is a little below $\frac \pi 2$, much greater than the upper limit of $\frac\pi 4$ that has been put on $\pi L$. Thus $\sin(x)/x$ is decreasing on that interval and $1-\sin(x)/x$ is increasing.